# C# - Problems on Connect to Synology NAS with Restsharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, synology

I can't manage to stablish a connection to Synology NAS from c# using RestSharp (or any other method)

```
    public void TryConnection()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("/webapi/entry.cgi", Method.Post);
        request.AddParameter("path", "entry.cgi");
        request.AddParameter("api", "SYNO.API.Info");
        request.AddParameter("version", "1");
        request.AddParameter("method", "query");

        var client = new RestClient(new RestClientOptions("http://quickconnect.to/FDesign-GmbH:5000/") { FollowRedirects = true });

        var response = client.ExecuteGetAsync(request).Result;
        
        string s = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
    }
```

Result = "Request failed with status code Redirect".

from what i found i believe this is having something to do with redirects but i dont know how to handle it...

if i paste this Url manualy in browser i get feedback :

https://192-168-178-23.fdesign-gmbh.direct.quickconnect.to:5001/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Info&version=1&method=query

same Url in Code:

```
    public void TryConnection()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("/webapi/entry.cgi", Method.Post);
        //request.AddParameter("path", "entry.cgi");
        request.AddParameter("api", "SYNO.API.Info");
        request.AddParameter("version", "1");
        request.AddParameter("method", "query");
        request.AddParameter("query", "SYNO.API.Auth,SYNO.FileStation");

        var client = new RestClient(new RestClientOptions("https://192-168-178-23.fdesign-gmbh.direct.quickconnect.to:5001/") { FollowRedirects = false });

        var response = client.ExecuteGetAsync(request).Result;
        
        string s = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
    }
```

with code i get : "Error sending request"

Some help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the full content of the returned message. I suspect this includes a redirect URL.

Comment: Yes, but that url in browser is wrong : "http://FDesign-GmbH:5000.quickconnect.to/webapi/entry.cgi?path=entry.cgi&api=SYNO.API.Info&version=1&method=query"

Comment: That would seem to be caused by a misconfiguration of the web api on the NAS side. But since it works with a normal browser, that is strange.

Comment: Have you tried using a GET-Request instead of a Post-Request here: 
var request = new RestRequest("/webapi/entry.cgi", Method.Get); //Instead of Method.Post

When you open it directly in the browser its usally a GET-Request not a POST-Request

Comment: @MarkusE :  Yes i have tried GET, same result.